# Monitoring of a memory allocation

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm developing on Linux/g++ and uses valgrind to verify memory usage. My question is:
How do I know where there is an allocation of memory in my application (including system libraries)? May be valgrind provides this functionality, or some similar tool.

Comment: When you run valgrind, it should tell you where there is allocations/free's

Comment: Or do you want to track this yourself?  Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: If no memory error (allocs == frees), then no messages about memory usage, but I want to know about allocations in any case.

Comment: ... and where it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to profile memory usage, have a look at [massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) (valgrind tool).
Also try the excellent [massif visualizer](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=122409) to visualize the results.

Answer (score 0):

gdb will allow you to monitor a specific memory section for writes and reads. You can set a break point on this. You can use the gdb 'watch' command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `--trace-malloc=yes`.

Comment: Yes, it looks like what I need, but output looks like "_Znaj(128) = 0x42FF060". Can I show it as a more readable?